# interpreting Normalized Differentiated Bareness Index and Normalized Differentiated Impervious Surfaces Index?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, ndvi, land-use

I've tried looking for various sources to help me interpret NDBaI and NDISI indices but I've not found anything particularly helpful.

Does anyone know how to do it or have any literature that might prove helpful?

I need to know if the values range from -1 to 1 like in other LULC indices or is it different for these two and what might each range correspond to(in terms of LULC classes).

Answer (score 2):

The word **normalized** means fitting all your observations between -1 and 1, hence all normalized indexes will have this range.

As for literature:

- [Use of Normalized Difference Bareness Index in Quickly Mapping Bare Areas from TM/ETM+](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4183057_Use_of_normalized_difference_bareness_index_in_quickly_mapping_bare_areas_from_TMETM) (Zhao, Hongmei; Chen, Xiaoling - 2005): this is the paper that created the NDBaI.

  > *NDBaI: (thermal - swir) / (thermal + swir)*
- [A Modified Normalized Difference Impervious Surface Index (MNDISI) for Automatic Urban Mapping from Landsat Imagery](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Cuizhen_Wang/publication/319656050_A_Modified_Normalized_Difference_Impervious_Surface_Index_MNDISI_for_Automatic_Urban_Mapping_from_Landsat_Imagery/links/59dbf9b3aca2728e20183715/A-Modified-Normalized-Difference-Impervious-Surface-Index-MNDISI-for-Automatic-Urban-Mapping-from-Landsat-Imagery.pdf) (Sun, Zhongchang; Wang, Cuizhen; Guo, Huadong; Shang, Ranran - 2017): though this paper works with a modified version of the index, they do cite the original index and explain the modifications applied.

  > *X: (MNDWI + nir + swir) / 3*
  >
  > *NDISI: (thermal - X) / (thermal + X)*

Comment: You assertion on normal variables is incorrect. A normalized variable can take any range but follows a Gaussian distribution. Although, it is common to have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one. It is not uncommon for these types of indexes to be scaled to 8 or 16 bit which could still be normalized without converting to float or being in a -1 to 1 range.